# How can I change the name of user's folder in Windows OS?

Tags: windows

I got a brand new laptop, which was installed Win 11 Pro and has been configurated a little by my friend (with my permission). When I received the laptop, I found the name of user's folder in C:\Users is my friend's name. So, I want to rename it to my name.

I have deleted the old account (with my friend's name) and set my own account as an Administrator with my own name. Then, I restart my computer. But I found the name of the user's folder in C:\Users is still my friend's name. I found similar questions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39318782/change-user-folder-name-in-windows-10) and [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1509324/in-windows-10-how-can-we-change-the-name-of-this-folder-under-c-users/1509342?noredirect=1#comment2729367_1509342) on the site, but that is for Win 10, the step 1 and step 5 in the respective post is not suitable for Win 11. I search on the web and found a few different methods (but not very reliable) to rename the user's folder. I need to change the name of the user's folder to my own. So, I post such a question here to ask for help. Thank you very much!

Comment: Please provide a concrete example. How is it incorrect? Are you perhaps confusing account name and display name?

Comment: @Daniel B, It was his name, not my own

Comment: The account that you deleted, and the new admin account, did they have the same name? If not the same, then it's impossible that the new account got the old name. What is possible is that the account delete was not complete and left the old folder. Check if the new folder exists, and if it does then you can't rename the old folder to be the same as an existing folder.

Comment: 1. The account that I deleted has his name, and the new admin account that I created has my name. So, they have different names.

Comment: 2. The new folder exists and has a temp name, I tried to rename the old folder to a name that I desired, which is of course not the same as the new folder's name, i.e. the temp name

Comment: It's unclear : Why do you want to rename the old folder? Why not concentrate of the new one (which I suppose is the one found in the registry)? If you can, better share the true names of the old and new accounts in your post, to clarify it. Tell us exactly what you did. (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add requested information or clarification, don't use comments for this purpose. I suggest to write the old and new name of the user and the folder in your question and describe what you did step by step.

Comment: Include also the registry updates that you did. There must have been some mistakes, since this procedure should also work in Windows 11.

Comment: @harrymc, please see my updated post, and I did not make any registry updates. Thank you!

Comment: @Bodo, please see my updated post, thank you!

Comment: Without exact details we cannot advance in helping you. Screenshots will be best.

Comment: To me it is still not clear. I suggest to write the actual visible name, the value of the environment variable `USERNAME` and the folder name before and after your changes with a step-by-step description. Example: Logged in in as user "Foo Bar", `USERNAME=foo`, folder was `C:\\Users\\foo`. Created new user "Baz Bletch" with `USERNAME=baz` and home folder `C:\\Users\\baz` etc. Or something like ... Renamed existing user "Foo Bar"  to "Baz Bletch" ...

Comment: The process is identical to that on Windows 10, you disconnect the account from the Microsoft Account and provide a new name for the profile, signout of the profile, and sign back into the profile and assign it to the desire Microsoft Account.

Comment: Best option: login a new user. That doesn't work? Reset the computer. That's pretty easy these days too.